# Restar en una misma columna con condiciones

Tags: android, base-de-datos, sqlite

me gustaría saber si alguien puede sugerirme algo para mi consulta (utilizo SQLITE)

Tengo una tabla con las sig columnas "monto", "descripcion" y un id en comun

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo es obtener el monto total agrupado por "fk" pero restando esa cantidad de los que en la descripción tengan "TRANSACCION".

Ejemplo: tengo $250 + $310 con fk = 1, quiero restarle la TRANSACCION con el mismo fk = 1 pero con un monto de $321, igualmente pasaria con el fk=2, agruparlos y restarle el monto que aparezca en su grupo fk=2 solo si en la descripción tiene el concepto de "TRANSACCION".

El resulltado esperado seria una tabla como la sig:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Saludos!

Comment: Recuerda que siempre tendrás mejores respuestas si agregas lo que has tratado, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
SELECT 
fk, SUM(CASE WHEN descripcion = 'TRANSACCION' THEN -1 * monto ELSE monto END) AS total
FROM tu_Tabla
GROUP BY fk;
```

el truco está en el case, donde restara el monto (`-1 * monto`) cuando  descripción sea igual a `TRANSACCION`

Comment: Perfecto! muchas gracias! Solo me quedo la duda de cual es la función del (-1) pero funciona como esperaba.

Comment: -1 * monto es para que el número sea negativo y entonces usando la suma sea resta